# Get the last value of multiple tags

Tags: influxdb

I need to get the last value of each sourceTag. Please let me know if this query is correct.

```
SELECT * FROM "measurement1" where rig = '338' and ( sourceTag = 't1' or sourceTag = 
't2' or sourceTag = 't3' ) group by sourceTag order by time desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost. Just change `SELECT *` to `SELECT last(*)`.